# Same code compiling in g++, but not in VS

Tags: c++

I am trying to run my code in Visual Studio 2015, and I get next error`expression must have a constant value`on `double x1[dim];`in next code snipped.

```
double fitness(const double x[], const int &dim) {
     double sum = 0.0;
     double x1[dim];
     ...
     return sum;
}
```

The same code runs without an error on `g++ 4.8`. So how can I do the same thing under Visual Studio 2015.

Is my problem with compiler or code implementation?

Comment: use std::vector or std::valarray

Comment: I am trying to avoid containers like std::vector or std::array.

Comment: Then you can use dynamic array (`new` and `delete`), although I would prefer std::vector over it unless there is a very compiling reason. BTW the reason your code does't work is, variable length array, aka, VLA, is a c99 feature and is supported by GCC as a extension by default (afaik GCC's default C++ dialect option is -std=gnu++98 with all gcc extensions  enabled ). MSVC traditionally has a bad support for C99 so this language feature is likely not available in MSVC.

Comment: `g++ -Wall -std=c++14 -pedantic test.cpp` wouldn't compile the above code since [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)s isn't part the C++ standard; C99 allows it but you should use `gcc` for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`double x1[dim];` is a VLA (variable length array). It is not standard C++.

The reason why it works on `gcc` is that `gcc` has an extension which allows VLAs. VS2015 doesn't, so that's why it doesn't compile (it has its own set extensions though, just not that one).

The best alternative is a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<double> x1(dim); //array of size dim
```

If you can't use that, you can still use a manual dynamic array (although that is not recommended):

```
double* x1 = new double[dim];
delete[] x1; //Don't forget to delete it when you are done
//Alternatively, create a class which wraps the dynamic array, so you can use RAII
```

Comment: @user3528438 Jup, missed that one. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using new you should assign it to a unique_prr. Alternatively use alloca

Comment: @doron I don't think `std::unique_ptr` supports arrays yet.

Comment: @Rakete1111 [`std::unique_ptr` supports arrays since it was standardized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). It has an overload specifically for arrays.

Comment: @nwp Oh wow, I must have missed that somehow sometime. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, when I wanted to use VLA on MSVC, a workaround was to use `alloca()` whenever I wanted or needed VLA feature on a compiler that does not support VLA.

Comment: light weight and simple and static-sized.